# Best rsync syntax for transfering a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ssh, rsync

I've found several rsync commands for moving my wordpress site from one local machine to a remote server. I've successfully used the following command suggested by another Stackoverflow user:

rsync -aHvz /path/to/sfolder name@remote.server:/path/to/remote/dfolder

Would you say that it's enough, or would you suggest other attributes?

It's my understanding that an SSH connection would be safer. How does this command change if I want to make it over SSH. Also are there other things to be done besides including the SSH command ( like generating/installing the keys etc etc ). I just starting so a detailed explanation for a noob would be very much appreciated.

Pakal

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of ways in which you can customize this powerful command. Don't worry about SSH, by default its using SSH. Rest of the options depend on your requirement. You can consider '--perms' to preserve permissions. Similarly '-t' preserves times. I don't know if its relevant in transfer of a site.

Also '-n' would show you a dry run of transfer scenario. '-B' switch allows you to override custom block size.

Probably you should have a look at options yourself and find the appropriate ones by running 'info rsync'.

Answer (score 0):

the above command will use ssh and i see no problems with it's general usage.